The horror movie with portal between TV and ceiling
I'm looking for horror movie which:

I thing belongs to 80'
there was portal between TV which was watchen by kids and the ceiling in the same room (the throw a ball by this portal first, and then they use rope to get kid back from beyond-world using TV)
on the end, if I rember well there was big tree outside the house with hollow-mouth which tries eat someone from the family
it is rather english-language movie


It sounds like you're describing Poltergeist (1982), but there are a few details a little mixed up.
The portal is in fact in the closet, not the TV. The exit is the ceiling, but it's in a different room, specifically the downstairs living room. They do demonstrate this by tossing a ball through first, and there is a rope that is passed through which is used to retrieve the missing girl.
The TV is important, though, as the white noise is how they are able to hear the little girl and learn that she's been taken through to this other realm.
And there is also a scene with a tree that tries to attack the girl's brother.

Yes, that's it. The facts are mixed up because I was watching it I think 20 years ago as a child.
